# Construct a field with $8$ elements question.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The proof starts with:

Let $x^3+x+1$ be a polynomial over field $\Bbb Z_2$.  Because it has no $0$'s it is irreducible and therefore $\Bbb Z_2[x] / \langle x^3 + x + 1 \rangle = \{ax^2 + bx + c + \langle x^3 + x + 1 \rangle: a, b, c \in \Bbb Z_2 \}$ is a field and has $8$ elements.

My question is, how is the field able to be written as this set?  and How are there only $8$ elements?

Comment: The field is written that way just by definition of a quotient ring, i.e. two equivalence classes $[p]$ and $[q]$ are the same if $p-q\in <x^3+x+1>$.

Comment: Furthermore, since your coefficients $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_2$, then you have $3^2=8$ choices for polynomials.

Comment: You can form a field of 8 polynomials choosing a, b, c which can take values from 0,1.  It has a zero, since the given irreducible polynomial will always give 1 and you can choose a,b,c to make a zero, so that you can define a field.

Comment: @Jake  By the definition of a quotient ring: $\Bbb Z_2 [x] / \langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle = \{ g(x) + \langle x^3 + x + 1 \rangle : g(x) \in \Bbb Z_2[x] \}$.  But how can every element in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ be written as $g(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$?

Comment: Every element in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ is not of the form $ax^2+bx+c$.  For example, $1+x+x^2+x^3$.  However, once you pass to the quotient ring, call it $R=\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/<x^2+x+1>$, then the elements of $R$ do "look" like (at most) quadratic polynomials.  This gets back to my earlier comment about when two elements in $R$ are the same.

The notation can be misleading.  elements in $R$ are equivalence classes, they are NOT polynomials.  You can show that each equivalence class can be written as a polynomial, and in your case there are exactly 8 equivalence classes.

Comment: I don't understand.  In $\Bbb Z_2[x] / \langle x^3 + x + 1 \rangle$, how is it that $x^5 + x^4 + x + \langle x^3 + x + 1 \rangle$  can be written as $ax^2 + bx + c + \langle x^3 + x + 1 \rangle$?

Comment: Is $x^5+x^4+x$ in the ideal generated by $x^3+x+1$?

Answer (score 6):

In the quotient, $x^3+x+1=0$, i.e $x^3=-x-1$. Therefore you can substitute every occurence of $x^3$ with $-x-1$. That means you can "cut down" the degree of every polynomial in the quotient to $2$ or lower which gives you the desired representation as a set. There are only $8$ elements in the field because you only have $2$ choices for each of the parameters $a,b,c$  ($0$ and $1$), which gives you $2^3=8$ elements.